# Open NavBar from Right To Left

Tags: html, nav

I want to open my nav sidebar from right to left but it is by default opening from left to right. I will provide the link to the code below. Thanks

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav

Comment: Do you mean to have your HTML in RTL? or is it just the menu location?

Comment: Fixed typo and format.

Answer (score 4):

If you change `left: 0;` to `right: 0;` in `.sidenav` in the CSS-Part, the sidenav will appear on the right side. I hope this is what you had in mind.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . that's exactly what i had in mind

Comment: Don't forget to click the tick underneath the upvote and downvote button to mark the answer as the correct one if it worked. @WasimKhan

Answer (score 0):

core is:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

now it will slide out from RIGHT TO LEFT, as oppose to left to rigth.

Use Width property to control the slide out!

video on this: https://youtu.be/710WRqbH2mc

ps: if you want the menu to slide from left to rigth, just set left: 0;  and remove right property;  then it will reverse itself.  =)